# Old / dark dialog boxes when using TStyleBook

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

This problem is highly related to the following question: [Why are all the dialogs are using the "old" Android 2.x style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27664134/1854856)

I'm using Delphi Berlin (10.1), where this problem has been fixed already:

[image]

But, as soon as a TStyleBook is dropped to the form and assigned to it (e. g. by right clicking a component and then "edit custom style"), the dialog boxes (all of them) turn to the dark style again:

[image]

The automatically created "trimmed" style is still the "light" version ("AndroidL Light"). And yes, I checked that function "GetNativeTheme()" in FMX.Helpers.Android.pas assigns the `Result`, I even copied the file and added it to the project. Removing the assignment from `Form1.StyleBook` show the native styled dialogs again.

How can this be solved while still keep using a TStyleBook?

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem: Function `GetNativeTheme()` was searching with `TStyleManager.FindStyleDescriptor()` in the assigned style for a `TStyleDescription` object entry, to look if one of the strings "[LIGHTSTYLE]" or "[DARKSTYLE]" is used for the target platform. In a full style file this object entry is normally present, but when starting to edit a custom style of a component inside the IDE, a TStyleBook component is created with just a small style. It cannot be seen inside the IDE, but this small style does not contain the `TStyleDescription` object entry, so the dark/light theme can not be found out. And by default, the `GetThemeFromDescriptor()` returns `0`, which seems to correspond to the dark/old style.

I solved the problem by double-clicking the TStyleBook component, save the style to a file (*.style), opened the file in a text editor and simply manually added the `TStyleDescription` object entry. Saved and loaded back to the IDE. Now all dialogs use the correct light style theme.

[image: Add the text marked with the red rectangle to the styles file]

Here again as text:

```
  object TStyleDescription
    StyleName = 'Description'
    Author = 'Embarcadero Technologies Inc.'
    AuthorURL = 'www.embarcadero.com'
    PlatformTarget = '[ANDROID][ANDROIDL][LIGHTSTYLE][DEFINEFONTSTYLES]'
    MobilePlatform = True
    Title = 'AndroidL Light'
    Version = '1.0'
  end
```

Comment: Looks like you need to submit a bug report to emba.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to StanE's answer:
Instead of adding a StyleDescription to all custom styles you can also modify the `GetThemeFromDescriptor()` function in `FMX.Helpers.Android` to return a default value of `TJAlertDialog.JavaClass.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`.