# System dialogs, like ShowMessage, using old style on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm building an application using Firemonkey with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, everything is fine, but when I use ShowMessage the dialog uses a style similar to that used in old Android versions and sometimes even with misaligned buttons.

The screenshots were taken from a Moto G5 running Android 9

Is there an option to change the default style of this dialogs?

[image: Dialog using ShowMessage]
[image: Dialog using a MessageDialog with buttons]

Comment: Check your theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and use minSDK 16 above and target sdk is 27 above

Comment: This question is already answered here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664134/why-are-all-the-dialogs-are-using-the-old-android-2-x-style)